# Count the number of n-bit strings such that, in each prefix of the string, the number of zeroes is at least k times the number of ones

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

How can we count the number of n-bit strings such that, in each prefix of the string, the number of zeroes is at least k times the number of ones?

Examples:

(1) With n = 5 and k = 3, there are 3 such strings: 00000, 00001, and 00010. In each of these strings, each initial substring has at least three times as many zeroes as ones.

(2) With n = 6 and k = 2, there are 8 such strings: 000000, 000001, 000010, 000011, 000100, 000101, 001000, and 001001.

I implemented it counting recursively, but I need a more efficient algorithm than that or a formula. It'd be nice if anyone could find a pattern in the outputs to avoid the time wasted on recursion.

To clarify the problem I'll state some constraints, 
1<=n<=1000;
1<=k<=n

For anyone wanting to see the code, this is my implemented recursive code-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count;
int k;

// c0 is no. of 0s and c1 is no. of 1s
void rec(int c0, int c1, int n)
{
    if(n>=0)
    {
        if(!n)
        {
            count++;
        }

        rec(c0+1,c1,n-1);

        if((c1+1)*k<=c0)
        {
            rec(c0,c1+1,n-1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin>>n>>k;
    rec(k,0,n-k);
    cout<<count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199214/discussion-on-question-by-jim-wald-count-the-number-of-n-bit-strings-such-that).

Comment: I changed “x” in your original title and text to “k” to make it clearer it was a parameter to the problem, avoiding anybody confusing it with an unknown to be solved for. It would be good to keep the notation consistent—either use k in subsequent edits or change all of the text and code back to using x.

Comment: Any nonconforming string necessarily has a prefix with exactly floor(m/(k+1))+1 ones, where m is the length of the prefix. I wonder if some straightforward combinatorics for counting such strings and use of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle could give a better summation than recursion.

Comment: @eric: Perhaps, but there is a simple DP solution which operates in quadratic time and linear space, and uses only one addition in the inner loop.

Comment: @rici: can you explain that DP solution?

Comment: For k=2, the number of strings appears to be [integer sequence A126042](https://oeis.org/A126042), which has a closed-form expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may be a more sophisticated solution involving combinatorial analysis, it is quite straightforward to produce a dynamic programming solution which works in O(n²) time and requires O(n) extra space. Since the inner loop of this solution involves only a single addition, it is quite fast until `n` gets large, although you do need multiprecision arithmetic for all but the smallest problems.

Dynamic programming involves turning recursion on its head; instead of starting with the target problem and recursively decomposing it into simpler problems, in dynamic programming we solve all the simpler problems in some appropriate order, so that we have the intermediate results before we need them. It's effective when the same simpler problem will show up many times during the recursion, which is the same use case for memoising recursion. DP can be a lot more efficient than memoising, though, because correct sequencing of the intermediate computations often means a significant reduction in the number of intermediate computations whose values need to be remembered at any given time. (It also avoids the overhead of checking whether the required intermediate value has already been computed, although that's not usually significant.)

In this case, we'll use a very simple recursion, which is based on the fact that any valid binary sequence of length `m` is a valid binary sequence of length `m-1` followed by either a `0` or a `1`. (It is not always possible to put a `1` on the end of a valid binary sequence, since that might violate the count constraint. But it is always possible to remove a `1` which happens to be at the end of a valid binary sequence.)

What we're actually going to count is the number of valid sequences of length `n` with exactly `m` ones. Then the number of valid sequences of length `n` can be obtained by adding all the counts for different values of `m`. And we can distinguish three cases:

1. `m` is too large; there are so many ones that it is not possible to construct a sequence where the number of ones is at least `k` times the number of zeros. It's easy to check for this condition; the number of zeros is `n - m` (since everything which is not a one must be a zero), so `m` is too large if `m > k(n - m)`. A little bit of algebra will show that this is the same as saying `m > n / (k + 1)`.
2. `m` is zero. There is exactly one valid sequence of length `n` with no ones: the sequence of `n` zeros. And that sequence is valid regardless of the value of `k`.
3. For every value of `m` greater than 0 and less than the cutoff in point 1 above, we can count the number of valid sequences with `m` ones by considering the two possible last values: a valid sequence must either be a valid sequence of length `n-1` with `m-1` ones, followed by another one, or a valid sequence of length `n-1` with `m` ones followed by a zero.

Putting all that together, we can recursively compute:

```
Count[n, m] = 1                               if m = 0
            = Count[n-1, m-1] + Count[n-1, m] if 0 < m ≤ n / (k + 1)
            = 0                               if m > n / (k + 1)
```

Now, let's turn that recursion into a dynamic programming solution.

It's clear that all of the values of `Count[n, ...]` for a given `n` depend only on values of `Count[n-1, ...]`. So if we compute all the values of `Count[n-1,...]`, we can use those to produce the vector of values of `Count[n, ...]`, after which we no longer need the remember any value for `Count[n-1, ...]`. So we clearly only need to keep two vectors of length `1 + (n / (k + 1))`. But we can do even better than that, since the value of `Count[n, m]` only depends on `Count[n-1, m]` and `Count[n-1, m-1]`. That fact lets us do the computation in place with a single vector, provided we work backwards starting with the largest valid value of `m`.

So the final solution for count valid bit sequences of length `n` where every prefix has at least `k` zeros for every one:

1. Create a vector `Count` of length 1 + (n / (k + 1)). Set Count[0] to 1 and every other element to 0.
2. For each `i` from 1 to `n` (inclusive):

   - For each `j` from `i / (k + 1)` down to 1 (inclusive):

     - Add `Count[j-1]` to `Count[j]`
3. Return the sum of all the values in `Count`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,i,j,m,n,k,sum;
    
    sum=0;
    
    cin>>n>>k;
    m=n/(k+1);
    
    int count[m+1]={0};
    count[0]=1;
    
    for(i=k+1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i/(k+1);j>=1;j--)
        {
            count[j]=count[j]+count[j-1];
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<m+1;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+count[i];
    }
    
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Using the suggestions given above I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Find the legal strings by construction, not trial-and-error.

Number the string positions form the left, starting at 1.  Let `j = k+1` for notational convenience.  The first `1` can appear no sooner than position `j`; the second no sooner than position `2j`, and so on.

For instance, with your case of (6, 2), j=3.  The first `1` can appear anywhere from position 3; the second could appear only in position 6.

Write a DP function to walk through this decision process.  Forget generating the string for now, all we need is all of the arrays in which each element `a[i]` is no less than `i*j`.  For the above case, the first decision point is for an initial element.  Choices include

```
[]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
```

The first and last of these are terminal searches; the others get extended for a possible second element, yielding

```
[3, 6]
[4, 6]
[5, 6]
```

... and these convert easily to the eight desired solutions.

Can you implement the recursion from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Trivial recursive solution
    // It appears that one on the recursive calls
    // can be removed as tail recursion
    // Appending multiple '0's, just until another '1' is possible,
    // seems to be a nice optimisation, but will complicate the
    // final logic (at the end-of string) and will need a few
    // extra conditions.

#include <stdio.h>

char buff[100];

unsigned recurse(unsigned zeros, unsigned ones, unsigned x, unsigned len)
{
unsigned count=0;
unsigned pos = zeros+ones;

if (pos == len) {
        buff[pos] =0;
        printf("%s\n", buff);
        return 1;
        }

buff[pos] = '0';
count += recurse(zeros+1, ones, x, len);
        // if no '1' is possible yet,
        // we could loop here, adding more '0' bits
        // , but we must take care not to exceed len
        // and to maintain the count correctly
        // (and possibly yield the resulting string)

if (ones < zeros /x) {
        buff[pos] = '1';
        count += recurse(zeros, ones+1, x, len);
        }

return count; // number of solutions, given the prefix [0..pos]
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned x,n, result;
sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &n);
sscanf(argv[2], "%u", &x);

result = recurse(0,0, x, n);
printf("Result=%u\n", result);
return 0;
}
```